# prevent mobile default keyboard while keeping text insertion cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

On mobile browsers, Is there a way to prevent the default keyboard (like when using the `readonly=true` property on the textarea) while keeping the caret or text insertion cursor functioning? 
To enable the user to choose a location inside the textarea, while not poping-out the keyboad?

Comment: Why do you want to keep **text insertion** working when you want a readonly field?

Comment: @w4rumy He doesn't want a readonly field, he's just using it as an example to explain the behaviour.

Comment: I don't get it. The user can choose any text on a webpage on a mobile browser (at least on Android and iOS), so why using a textarea anyway?

Comment: That's a good question, we could use some more details - what do you want this for?

Comment: Simple, I have a different input system that I want to use instead of the default mobile keyboard, but I still want to let the user choose where exactly he wants the input to be within the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that this would stop the keyboard from appearing, but this would keep the user from typing in the textarea:

```
<textarea maxlength="0">Put your text here</textarea>
```

Keep in mind that this isn't supported in Internet Explorer below 9, and it is not supported in Opera. Seeing that you are aiming for mobile devices, this shouldn't really be a problem.